HELP! Attaching a file from an Object to an email action in Flow when using an email template
I have a reminder email flow setup that sends a reminder email to an approver depending on the step it's in.
How would I attach a file to an email template via an email that's sent out with an Action from Flow? The file(s) are uploaded and housed in the Files portion of a custom object...
I created a Get Record Action grabbing the LinkedEntityId field from the Content Document Link object and tried assigning it multiple ways into a collections variable to use in the email action but it's a no go...
Any ideas how/if this can be done without Apex or an addon??



if your attachment contains dynamic data; you could use Visualforce email templates and attachments

I'm not aware of any way to do this with the standard email alert action.  But there are add-ons that accomplish this.  I'll link them below.
https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/
